# javascript accessing member of a static class

Tags: javascript

I have the following in the  section of my page:

```
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
    <script language='javascript' src='scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
    <script language='javascript' src='scripts/NumberMaze.js'></script>
    <script language='javascript' src='scripts/GameConfig.js'></script>
    <script language='javascript' src='scripts/UIManager.js'></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var game = new NumberMaze();
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

GameConfig.js contains:

```
(function(undefined) {
    NumberMaze.GameConfig           =   function() {
        return {
            minCanvasWidth          :   320,
            minCanvasHeight         :   240,
            maxCanvasWidth          :   640,
            maxCanvasHeight         :   480,
        };
    };
})();
```

NumberMaze.js contains:

```
(function($, undefined) {
    NumberMaze          =   function() {
        console.log(NumberMaze.GameConfig.minCanvasWidth);
        console.log(NumberMaze.GameConfig);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

For the logs in NumberMaze.js I am getting the following output. How do I access the value of minCanvasWidth. Whats wrong with my code?

```
undefined
function () {
        return {
            minCanvasWidth          :   320,
            minCanvasHeight         :   240,
            maxCanvasWidth          :   640,
            maxCanvasHeight         :   480,
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your log shows, you have a *function* stored in `NumberMaze.GameConfig`; not the actual object with data.

You have to *call* the function to get the object, since the function `return`s the object:

```
console.log(NumberMaze.GameConfig().minCanvasWidth);
```

However, why not set the object directly instead of wrapping it inside a (seemingly useless) function?

```
(function(undefined) {
    NumberMaze.GameConfig = {
        minCanvasWidth    :   320,
        minCanvasHeight   :   240,
        maxCanvasWidth    :   640,
        maxCanvasHeight   :   480,
    };
})();
```

That way, both of your logs just work.

Comment: aww.. GameConfig is a function. right.. thx for pointing it out :)